# How can I get my jQuery mouseover tooltip to follow the mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery code:

```
$('.box_class').bind('mouseover', function(e){
   $('.tooltip').css({'top':e.pageY,'left':e.pageX, 'z-index':'1'});
   $('.tooltip').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

It works fine, but I want that message would always follow the mouse pointer and now, when I "mouseover" on `box_class` it always stays at the same point. I probably should change `mouseover` function to another? Or how should I implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mousemove:

```
$('.box_class').bind('mouseover', function(e){
   $('.tooltip').fadeIn("fast");
}); 

$('.box_class').bind('mousemove', function(e){
   $('.tooltip').css({'top':e.pageY,'left':e.pageX, 'z-index':'1'});
});
```

Keep your `mouseout` or `mouseleave` observer to close the tooltip.

Comment: I swear the god I tried mousemove and it didn't work... Omg... Thanks. But I think I don't have separate fade and mousemove, don't I?

Comment: Well you'll want to separate them or the tooltip will be constantly fading in as you move the mouse :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the position set to absolute? If not try:

```
position:absolute;
```